# DATEDIFF constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want it so that when the difference between a date in one of the columns and the system date have a difference of more the 6 months, one of the other values in the table changes.

```
ALTER TABLE MEDICAL_CERTIFICATE
ADD CONSTRAINT MC_CLASS1 
CHECK(DATEDIFF(mm, LAST_RENEWAL_DATE, SYSDATE) < 6  AND CLASS = '1' OR CLASS = '2');
```

The program comes back with an invalid identifier error.

I need it so if the last renewal date and current date have a difference of more than 6 months the class changes from 1 to 2.

Comment: Try `SYSDATETIME()`.

Comment: You said "constraint" and then you said "one of the other values in the table changes". A constraint cannot change the content of a row. In addition, it is evaluated when the row is inserted or modified - your description implies that this should be checked every day. I think it is time to step back and think about your goal here since a constraint does not seem to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't recognize `SYSDATE`, unless that is a column in your table.  You can try this:

```
ALTER TABLE MEDICAL_CERTIFICATE ADD CONSTRAINT MC_CLASS1 
    CHECK (DATEDIFF(month, LAST_RENEWAL_DATE, GETDATE()) < 6 AND 
           CLASS IN (1, 2)
          );
```

Note that I changed the logic for `CLASS`.  This is probably what you intend.  I am guessing `CLASS` is a number, so I removed the single quotes (put them back in if it is a string).

You may not understand how `DATEDIFF()` works.  It counts the number of month boundaries between two dates.  So, if today is any day in July, then this is true only for days before February.

If you want six actual months, then use date comparisons:

```
ALTER TABLE MEDICAL_CERTIFICATE ADD CONSTRAINT MC_CLASS1 
    CHECK (LAST_RENEWAL_DATE < DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) AND
           CLASS IN (1, 2)
          );
```